# How to save image to PDO database

Tags: php

I currently have a database connection and a profile Model. I am able to save the username in a controller like so

```
if(isset($_POST['action'])){
        $user= $this->model('User');
        $user->username= $_POST['username'];
```

How can I save a profile picture to this user? 
I have tried

```
        $file = $_FILES['file']; //get file
        $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name']; //get file name
        $file_tempDir = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; // temp name
        $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size']; // file size
        $file_errorMsg = $_FILES['file']['error']; // error msg
        $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type']; //file type
        $file_convertedExtension = strtolower(pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // to lower to avoid upper case extensions

        //Allow files to have the same name
        $file_uniq = uniqid('', true). "." . $file_convertedExtension;

        // Make sure extension is allowed*
        if(in_array($file_convertedExtension, $possible_extensions)){
            $file_saveDestination = '../images/' . $file_uniq;    
            move_uploaded_file($file_tempDir, $file_saveDestination);
        }
        else{
            echo "This type of file extension is not allowed.";
        }
```

**$user->user_images= $file_uniq;**

But this doesn't work. **$user->user_images = $_POST['file']** seems to add to the databse but I don't know if it's correct

Also move_uploaded_file($file_tempDir, $file_saveDestination); doesn't seem to be saving anything in the destination

Comment: You need to add more checks, you are not checking if there are any errors with uploading the image and `move_uploaded_file` returns true on success and false if there was an error: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: @Second2None Ok thanks for reply, but how do I save it do the database? Was i doing it correctly?

Comment: That code doesn't save to a database, you would need to include that code and what framework you are using, what you have posted moves a temporary uploaded file to a new directory. You would save the path of the file to the database.`'../images/' . $file_uniq` assuming this exists and is correct.

Comment: I tried $user->user_images= $file_uniq; but it doesnt work,